# Java JDBC Email PrintStackFree

Tags: java, email, jdbc

I have a program which reads a data from database and does some calculations. I have it in try and catch statements and printing the error using e.printstackfree(). However, is there a way we can email the error instead of outputting the error to the user.

Such as:

```
 try{
   Statement  stmt = connection.createStatement();
   ............
 }catch(SQLException e){
   System.err.print("\nDriver Error: " +"'" + e.getMessage()+"'");
   e.printStackFree();
  //email e.printStackFree() using javax mail API

 }
```

Now, what i am thinking is that what if i used javax mail API to email the error. Again, question is how can i do it?

This is what i have so far:

```
try{
      Statement  stmt = connection.createStatement();
     ............
}catch(SQLException e){
 final Message message;

 Properties props = System.getProperties();
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
 message = new MimeMessage(session);
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("fromEmail@gmail.com")); //from

message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("toEmail@gmail.com"));

message.setSubject("Testing Error");

message.setContent("'"+e+"'", "text/html");

Transport.send(message);
System.out.println("Sent Email!!!");

}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually isnt that hard :D

```
try{
   Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
   .......................
} catch (Exception e) {
     String host = "smtp.google.com";
     String sender= "fromEmail@gmail.com";
     String recipiant = "toEmail@mail.com";

     StringWriter tracewriter = new StringWriter();
     e.printStackTrace(tracewriter);
     String trace = tracewriter.toString();

     Properties props= System.getProperties();
     props.setPropertie("mail.smtp.host", host);

     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

     try{
         MineMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
         message.addRecipiant(Message.RecipiantType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipiant));
         message.setSubject("Testing Error");
         message.setText(trace);

         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("An administrator has been notified");
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

We simply pass the `StringBuilder` to the `printStackTrace` method of the exception, read the combined string with `toString` and send this as an email.

Now you should be able to send emails whenever there is an exception coming from the database query and whatever else you are doing in that try.

Comment: Would'nt having e.printStackTrace(trace) before you initialize the variable will give you error...Also, i don't think the tracewriter actually reads any string. Can you please explain? And, thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: Never mind got it to fixed! I did this way: e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(tracewriter)); String trace = tracewriter.toString();

Comment: No problem, and thanks for pointing out the mistake with `e.printStackTrace(trace)`. That was a typo :D. It was meant to say `e.printStackTrace(tracewriter)`. Fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

e.printStackTrace() can be passed a PrintStream or PrintWriter.  This lets you output the stack trace to someplace other than System.out.

One good place to "output" it to, is a StringWriter.  It is in memory and writes to a String.  Then you can add it to your email message.